# What .NET 7 version can I use with Xcode 14.2?

Tags: c#, ios, macos, maui

I'm trying to build a .NET/C# app on MacOS. My dev tools are:

- MacOS 12.7.2
- Xcode 14.2
- Visual Studio for Mac 17.6.7
- The following NET 7 SDKs: `7.0.100`, `7.0.311`

I've also added the following `global.json` file in the root of my Solution, in order to control the used framework:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "7.0.100",
    "rollForward": "disable",
    "allowPrerelease": false
  }
}
```

My Project file contains:

```
<TargetFramework>net7.0-ios</TargetFramework>
<SupportedOSPlatformVersion>14.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
```

If I build the C# project, I get the following error:

> This version of Microsoft.iOS requires the iOS 16.4 SDK (shipped with
> Xcode 14.3). Either upgrade Xcode to get the required header files or
> set the managed linker behaviour to Link Framework SDKs Only (to try
> to avoid the new APIs).

Being on Monterey, I am not able to install Xcode 14.3. Also setting the linker to "Link Framework SDKs Only" does not solve.

I'm assuming the choosen .NET version "7.0.100" is not compatible with my setup. If so, what .NET 7 framework version should I target in order to be able to build in my environment?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved by keeping `.NET 7.0.100` but forcing the installation of the previous workload `ios 16.2.2054`, by creating the following `rollback.json` file:

```
{
  "microsoft.net.sdk.ios": "16.2.2054/7.0.100"
}
```

And running these commands:

```
dotnet workload uninstall ios
dotnet workload install ios --from-rollback-file rollback.json
```